# CalendarService.Events.List.Fields property

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I am using .NET Client Library V3 to work with calendar items. How can I use the "Fields" property in `CalendarService.Events.List`? It takes a string so I tried passing a comma separated string but I am getting an error.

Note: I am trying to get the Fields to work since all fields are coming back null when running the query using ".Execute()". Maybe I need to bind to a specific calendar item ?

```
var calendarService = new CalendarService(initializer);
var asdfs12 = calendarService.Events.List("zoolander@dodgeball.com");
asdfs12.MaxResults = 300;           
asdfs12.TimeMin = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20);
asdfs12.TimeMax = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
asdfs12.Fields = "organizer,description";
Events asdfs = asdfs12.Execute();
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Do you get the right content of while you comment asdfs12.Fields = ...?

Comment: Thanks guys! It turns to be permission issue which I posted on
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387648/google-calendar-permission

Comment: Event title and description was coming back null. It turns out that I had to go into calendar manually and grant permission.